#  Resizing the form elements on resizing the form

Tags: c#, picturebox

how to Resizing the Windows form elements on resizing the form? is there any way to set the width of picturebox, panel, etc 100% like CSS? suggest me some help for best practices of layout? When i resize the Windows form, I want that Image size also change when i resize the image. like Windows Picture Viewer

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would probably be okay with the Anchor property of the controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [Control Docking](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908), it'll probably suit your needs.

Comment: i use this. But Image stills on that original size. When i resize the form, I want that Image size also chnage when i resize the image. like Windows Picture Viewer

Answer (score 1):

What you may want is to set the properties of the image control to fill the image inside.

Steps:

1. I created a new windows form
2. I added a picture box to the form
3. I set the picture box "Dock" property to "Fill"
4. I added an image to the picture box
5. I set the SizeMode property to "StretchImage" ("Zoom" might better fit your needs")

Comment: Yes It's working, But it's not maintain the ratio of Image Display size. Is there any way to resizing the display with maintain the ratio. Like Windows Picture Viewer. WPV maintain the ration when i resize the form of WPV. It's resize the image size display maintaining the ratio.