# Resize form as if it were a picture

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am using visual studio 2017's form designer, and I found no way to resize a form, in a way that simulates picture resizing. When i resize a form to be bigger by 25% I want all items inside to grow by 25%, and the spacing between each control to grow by that amount, and between a control and the borders of the form to grow by 25%.

I attached a gif of the situation

[What happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ1D8.gif)

[When using anchor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOch9.gif)

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx8zn.gif)

Can someone point me to a library/way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe, this links will be helpful: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070139/resizing-the-form-elements-on-resizing-the-form)(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070139/resizing-the-form-elements-on-resizing-the-form), (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942682/resize-controls-when-form-resize)(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942682/resize-controls-when-form-resize) .

Comment: you can use AutoScaleMode & AutoSizeMode

Comment: I already tried using dock and anchor, the problem is that the controls maintain the spacing in absolute distance, that means that if i increase the form's size, the spacing between the controls and the borders will grow correctly, but the spacing between each control remains the same. I edited the question to reflect that

Comment: This seems like an XY problem to me. Data entry forms are not pictures, so it's highly unusual to try to treat them as such. Your preview shows that even the title bar and standard windows chrome (form icon, max/min/close buttons) also scale when shrunk. If your goal is to adapt to different screen sizes, proportions, Windows itself does a lot of that for you. What's the actual goal here--and what's the use case?

Comment: @J.Joe Can you mention to which side/sides are you anchoring ?

Comment: Each one is anchored in accordance to it's position, the label and textbox are anchored to the top left, top left button to the top left, top right is anchored to the top right, bottom left to bottom left and bottom right to bottom right

Comment: Try Anchoring controls to all sides.

Comment: When you anchor to all sides, for some reason, the controls don't change position at all but rather change the size, that means that if you were to set the form to full screen, all the controls will overlap each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not woking out of the box; I still don't think this is very useful; but maybe your **special** application **does** need it..

This is the result of the few lines below:

[image]

So here is the example code:

First we need to set up things by **storing the old** bounds as well as the original parent sizes in the `Tag` of each control:

```
    // pick the top parent; in my case it wa a TabPage (not shown)
    Control ctrl = pickTheParent;  
    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls) StoreBounds(ctrl, c);
    ctrl.Resize += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)  ScaleBounds(c);
    };
```

We have also hooked up a sizing routine to the parent's `Resize` event.

Both the storing and the sizing must happen to **all** controls, inclding **nested** ones; so they are recursive..:

```
void StoreBounds(Control parent, Control ctl)
{
    ctl.Tag = new Tuple<Size, Rectangle>(parent.ClientSize, ctl.Bounds);
    // **
    foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls)  StoreBounds(ctl, c);
}


void ScaleBounds(Control ctl)
{
    ctl.Bounds = ScaledBounds(ctl);
    foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls)  ScaleBounds(c);
}
```

The sizing simply calculates the old ratios and from them the new ones:

```
Rectangle ScaledBounds(Control c)
{
    if (c.Tag == null) return c.Bounds;
    Rectangle old = ((Tuple<Size, Rectangle>)c.Tag).Item2;
    Size frame1 = ((Tuple<Size, Rectangle>)c.Tag).Item1;
    Size frame2 = c.Parent.ClientSize;
    float rx = 1f * frame2.Width / frame1.Width;
    float ry = 1f * frame2.Height / frame1.Height;
    int x = (int)(old.Left * rx);
    int y = (int)(old.Top * ry);
    int w = (int)(old.Width * rx);
    int h = (int)(old.Height * ry);
    return new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
}
```

Note that for the shown effect I had to turn off any `AutoSize` properties.

Also note that all `Anchors` (and any `Docks`) were **removed**. To do that automatically you can add a line of code or two in the storing code (**)..:

```
 ctl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
```

Removing the `Docking` is up to you, maybe some, like `Fill`, are actually still useful..?

Also note the example deals strictly with `Size` and `Location`; no other properties are affected. For some, most notably the `Fonts`, one could add more code ; e.g. add a 3rd `Item` to the `Tuple` to store the original `FontSize`.. For others, like `Border` widths no reasonably sizing method comes to mind.

The `PictureBox` obviously was set to `Zoom`.